# Simplify - Help

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am supposed to simplify this:

$$(x^2-1)^2 (x^3+1) (3x^2) + (x^3+1)^2 (x^2-1) (2x)$$

The answer is supposed to be this, but I can not seem to get to it:

$$x(x^2-1)(x^3+1)(5x^3-3x+2)$$

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this

$$x(x^2-1)(x^3+1)\Bigg[3x(x^2-1)+2(x^3+1)\Bigg]$$

Answer (score 0):

$$(x^2-1)^2 (x^3+1) (3x^2) + (x^3+1)^2 (x^2-1) (2x)$$
Factor out the $(x^2-1)$ term to get
$$(x^2-1)\left((x^2-1) (x^3+1) (3x^2) + (x^3+1)^2(2x)\right)$$
then factor out the $(x^3+1)$ term to get
$$(x^2-1)(x^3+1)\left((x^2-1) (3x^2) + (x^3+1)(2x)\right)$$
then factor out the $x$ term to get
$$x(x^2-1)(x^3+1)\left((x^2-1) (3x) + (x^3+1)(2)\right)=x(x^2-1)(x^3+1)(5x^3-3x+2)$$

Answer (score 0):

$$(x^2-1)^2 (x^3+1) (3x^2) + (x^3+1)^2 (x^2-1) (2x)\\=x(x^2-1)(x^3+1)\left[3x(x^2-1)+2(x^3+1)\right] \color{blue}{\text{(Factor out common factors)}}\\=x(x^2-1)(x^3+1)\left[3x^3-3x+2x^3+2\right] \color{blue}{\text{ (Distribute inside brackets)}}\\=x(x^2-1)(x^3+1)(5x^3-3x+2) \color{blue}{\text{ (Simplify)}}$$